# Civilization V LAN save via Internet

Tags: civilization-5

I've played with my friend a LAN game at his place. Unfortunately he lives quite far from me and I can't visit him on regular basis.

Can I use a save where we played via LAN to play with him via internet?

Comment: So resume a game over internet that you initiated with a LAN connection?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do.

Comment: Hehe. Googling for an answer I found the answer already on our site. So it is possible :)

Comment: Oh yeah! It's the same problem, thanks for pointing this out :)

Comment: No problemo. Have fun playing!